# Manually populate Rails databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a Rails way to manually populate databases? I can use PostgreSQL with SQL Inserts but I was wondering if there was a *Rails way*

Comment: The table is "products". They won't change in the future. I have to add them to the database by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you could add create statemants to `db/seeds.rb` and run `rake db:seed`

```
Product.create( 
  [ 
    { :price => 120.00, :item => "table" },
    { :price => 49.99, :item => "chair" }
  ]
)
```